# qdbus multiple interfaces in the same object path

Tags: dbus, qdbus

I need to know how to expose multiple interfaces in a same object path under a service using QDbus bindings in the dbus server. I use qdbusxml2cpp to generate the adaptor classes.
The structure below could make the question clear.

```
MyService (Service Name)
/org/demo (Object path)
org.demo.interface1 (Adaptor classA)
methodA
signalA
org.demo.interface2 (Adaptor classB)
methodB
signalB
```

Please help me by giving the example code if possible.

Comment: In general it should be possible: http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-faq.html#idp48032144

Answer (score 0):

I just spent the last few hours fighting with this myself. Here it is how to do it:

1. `class MyService : public QObject, public QDBusContext` has private members `m_interface1' and 'm_interface2'
2. the `interface1` and `interface2` classes are *derived* from the `QDBusAbstractAdaptor` (derived) class
3. when instantiating `interface1` and `interface2` use as parent `MyService` pointer for them
4. register `MyService` pointer to D-Bus using `QDBusConnection::registerObject("/", myService)`